# Python Error Init of Class

Tags: python, class, init

Below is my code. It is giving me a compile error saying that artist has not been defined. This confuses me since artist is a parameter I'm passing.

Thanks.

```
class Track:
def __init__(self, artist, title, album=None):
    self.artist = str(artist)
    self.title = str(title)
    self.album = album

def __str__(self):
    return self.artist + " " + self.title + " " + self.album

def set_album(self, album):
    self.album = album
```

class Album:
    def **init**(self, artist, title, year='', genre='', tracks=None):
        self.artist = str(artist)
        self.title = str(title)
        self.year = str(year)
        self.genre = str(genre)
        self.tracks = tracks

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.artist + " " + self.title + " " + self.year + " " + self.genre + " " + self.tracks

def add_track(track):
    self.tracks.append(track)
```

def music_library(tracks, albums):

```
while true:
    command = raw_input("Please enter a command (s, st or sa)").lower()

    if "s " in command:
        searchText = command.split()(1)

    elif "sa " in command:
        searchText = command.split()(1)

    elif "st " in command:
        searchText = command.split()(1)
```

import os
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
def load_library(dir):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.lower().endswith(".mp3"):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, filename)
            print "\n%s" % fullname
            try:
                audio = MP3(fullname)
                for key in audio:
                    print "  %s: %s" % (key, str(audio[key]))
            except:
                print "Error on %s" % fullname
```

That is the entire file. I am running it using

python musiclib.py

Comment: Provide the complete code and the complete traceback and don't throw incomplete class definitions in front of our feet.

Comment: This code is running fine.

Comment: Why do you need str() here?

Comment: It works on my machine. How are you using it?

Comment: Are you initializing the class?  You need to do that first.

Comment: I added the full code. All I am doing is running the file in Python using python musiclib.py

Comment: And which line has the error?

Comment: Where is the traceback?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tUMMlwP.png

Comment: When I "s/\t/    /g" it works on my machine

Comment: Your code has inconsistent indentation, due to tabs, which makes it difficult to tell if the indentation errors are the code you are running or just in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because you're mixing tabs and spaces.  When I copy and paste your code and look at it, I see:

```
'    class Track:'
'    \tdef __init__(self, artist, title, album=None):'
'    \t\tself.artist = str(artist)'
'            self.title = str(title)'
'            self.album = album'
'    '
'    \tdef __str__(self):'
'    \t\treturn self.artist + " " + self.title + " " + self.album'
'    '
'    \tdef set_album(self, album):'
'    \t\tself.album = album'
```

Mixing tabs and spaces confuses Python about how far code is indented.  Switch to using four spaces for indentation, and run your code using `python -tt yourprogramname.py` to confirm this diagnosis.